# Android get session cookie from webview

Tags: android, android-webview, session-cookies

I have en app with a webview to display an e-shop website.
For various reason the login par is made in a native form with a **DefaultHttpClient** and **HttpPost**.

When the user start by login, i have no problème to save the session cookie from the request to the webview cookie store.

My problem is when the user first navigate through the webview an login after, i cant retrive the webview cookie session from the cookiestore to put it to my **DefaultHttpClient**

this is my code :

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(clientConnectionManager, params);

String[] keyValueSets = cookieManager.getCookie(context.getString(R.string.cookie_domaine)).split(";");
           for(String cookie : keyValueSets)
           {
               String[] keyValue = cookie.split("=");
               String key = keyValue[0];
               String value = "";
               if(keyValue.length>1) value = keyValue[1];
               BasicClientCookie2 cookieForRequest = (BasicClientCookie2) new BasicClientCookie2(key, value);
               cookieForRequest.setDomain(context.getString(R.string.cookie_domaine));

               cookieForRequest.setPath("/");
               client.getCookieStore().addCookie(cookieForRequest);
           }
```

In debug i see my session cookie but the **getCookie** method dont return it, i think it's because the cookie session domain start with a dot.

How can i maintain my **webview** session to a **DefaultHttpClient** request?

Comment: Hey.! I'm facing exactly this problem.
How did you solve it.?
I'd be glad if you helped.

Comment: Unfortunately nobody help me, but i found a confirmation in the android source code, a cookie domain can't start with a dot.